# Make image full width by ignoring grid (but remain responsive)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have an image within multiple div's to be full-width.

I did some research in previous answers concerning this topic but it somehow didn't work out for me. So here's my situation:

On the page https://maisoncyclo.ch/collections/de-marchi I'd like to have the top image to be full-width up to it's original size (max 100%, 2048x2048px). The problem is that this image is within a `<p>` and a content-div and therefore respects the margins of its parents.

**What's the solution to make this image full-width to the users browser size?**

If I add a new CSS-Class for this type of image, what CSS code is required for this element?

**Current HTML:**

```
<div id="collection-description" class="desktop-push-2 desktop-8 tablet-6 mobile-3">

<div class="rte">
<p style="text-align: left;"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1129/3176/files/DEMARCHI_Header_2048x2048.jpg?9976235918523909588" alt="De Marchi Italien"></p>
```

**Current CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
}
*, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Inherited from p
Style Attribute {
    text-align: left;
}
p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

Inherited from div.rte
.rte {
    text-align: left;
}
Inherited from body.gridlock.collection
body {
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Nitti Light, Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;`
```

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

It's more an hack than a real solution but this is what I would use if you can't change the html structure.

```
.rte > p > img {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

-

**Alternative**

A more suited solution would be placing the image outside the container div, which sets the content width.

Below a simple example using Bootstrap

```css
.full-w-img > img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

h1,p {
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1> Example </h1>
</div>

<div class="full-w-img">
  <img src="http://p-hold.com/kitten/1000/400">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore magni soluta cupiditate provident, incidunt, consequuntur iste earum beatae sequi nesciunt vero laboriosam, minima. Sapiente, blanditiis nobis ipsam accusantium neque soluta.</p>
  <p>Corrupti ipsum eius ipsa, autem reiciendis. Officia quia adipisci at, velit odio soluta facilis non ab laboriosam quos optio voluptatibus amet esse eos debitis, et. Ducimus et qui nisi officia.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Hm, that somehow really is just a hack because the lack of good responsiveness. What would be the ideal solution with a different HTML structure? Placing the image outside the div?

Comment: @Danielfrommaisoncyclo.ch Exactly, you have to place the image outside the container div. I updated my answer with an example. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

.full-width img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

<div class="container">
   <div class="full-width">
         <img src="/link/exmaple">
      </div>
</div>
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/